# Which service in AZURE provides server less HIVE likewise AWS provides Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, presto, amazon-athena, azure-data-lake

AWS provides us Athena to run server less Hive queries,
Is Azure has any service where we can run server less Hive queries.

Comment: Athena is based on Presto. It accepts ANSI SQL queries, not Hive queries (Hive QL). Let me update the tags on this question.

Answer (score 1):

@The Joker. I believe the Azure service for Hive you are looking for is HDInsight.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/hdinsight-use-hive

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But HDInsight is not a server less, I am looking for the server less service, likewise AWS has Athena which is a server less service to run hive queries. Does Azure has server less Hive service ?

Comment: Maybe you can explain your point of view for "server-less" as this term is kind of misleading when still actually does use some form of hardware.    Azures Serverless Compute Product doesn't specifically tag  itself with Hive, HDInsight does, but should be able to run any supported application.

Comment: Like Amazon [Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/?whats-new-cards.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&whats-new-cards.sort-order=desc) is an interactive query service that makes it easy to analyze data in Amazon S3 using Hive. Athena is serverless, so there is no infrastructure to manage, and you pay only for the queries that you run.